# var_dump() outputs nothing on HTTP POST

Tags: php, post, google-calendar-api

I have a rather interesting situation where I have [Google Calendar API v3](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api) calling my webhook.php using HTTP POST.

In my webhook I would use var_dump() in order to follow variable changes, and I print those var_dump()-ed variables to a file, but I receive no output nor error using var_dump. As far as I know, var_dump() is supposed to output at least an error, NULL or zero array (see example [here](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cde71b37fc8f47402e3e7dd73c909a02f7c24eaf), made by @ADyson).

On another not I am also not seem to be able to use [getallheaders()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php), but that might be due to Apache module not being installed on my provider server.

What can possibly be the reason I cannot use var_dump() as intended?

UPDATE:

As per request here is an example:

```
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_URI"], $_SERVER["HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID"])) {
    $calendarId = urldecode(substr($_SERVER["HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_URI"], 49, 54));
    $logFile = fopen("test.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = " something \n ".
        var_dump($calendarId);
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

In the above example, I can see '*something*' is inserted, but the output of var_dump() is not. I need to use var_dump() since I want to write an array to a file to see its contents. So to sum it up, situation is the following, when I try to output to a file:

```
$foo = json_encode($bar); // this I can see inserted to the file
$foo = var_dump(json_encode($bar)); // this I can see inserted to the file
```

Comment: Why would _you_ receive any "output"? _You_ did not request the script - Google's machines did. They are playing the part of the client in this instance.

Comment: If you want to output any debug information - then you need to write them to a file or something, so that you can check what that contains afterwards.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]'

Comment: @CBroe This is exactly what I meant. I was using fopen, fwrite and fclose in order to capture the information and the space where I would see my variable is blank.

Comment: _"I can see 'something' is inserted, but the output of var_dump() is not"_ - that's because var_dump writes directly to the output buffer, so you can not "concatenate" it into a string variable like this. You can use f.e. print_r or var_export instead, these both have a second parameter that can make them return the value, instead of outputting it directly. Or encode it as JSON.

Comment: @CBroe please repost this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can see 'something' is inserted, but the output of var_dump() is not

That's because `var_dump` writes directly to the output buffer, so you can not "concatenate" it into a string variable like this.

You can use f.e. `print_r` or `var_export` instead, these both have a second parameter that can make them return the value, instead of outputting it directly. Or encode it as JSON.